# Slang or figure or speech?

Tags: slang, figures-of-speech

"I told **everyone and their mother** about how I won the contest."

"Everyone and their mother" meaning that I told many many people.

Would this be considered slang or just a figure of speech?

Comment: You would just use _everyone_ which also includes _their mothers_.

Comment: It's both a slang expression and a use of *hyperbole*, which is a kind of figure of speech.

Comment: I think it would be interesting to ask about the *origin* of this expression.  I don't see it listed in *Green's Dictionary of Slang*

Comment: The version I'm more familiar with, though it's now old-fashioned, is "all the world and his wife".

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime It's on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everyone_and_their_mother), [FreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/everyone+and+their+mother) and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a figure of speech, the more traditional version being (as Kate Bunting has commented) '[All] the world and his wife'.

To use the sentence literally:
"I told everyone and their mothers about how I won the contest." would suggest that you told all the other competitors, their mothers and anyone who stands still for long enough.